# Realm primary key migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to migrate my realm schema to a new version. Therefor the removal of my primary key is needed.

Old schema:

```
class StudyState : Object
{
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var x = ""
  dynamic var y = ""

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "name"
  }
}
```

New schema:

```
class StudyState : Object
{
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var x = ""
  dynamic var y = ""
}
```

**Without migration**, realm will fail with

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'StudyState' due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'name' is no longer a primary key.'

I tried this **migration block**, which failed too:

```
migration.enumerate(StudyState.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
  newObject?["deleted"] = false
  newObject?["primaryKeyProperty"] = ""
 }
```

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid property name'

Is there a way to remove the primary key when migrating realm to a new schema version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to do anything in migration block if you only remove the primary key annotation.
But there is a need to increase the schema version because schema definitions changed.

Like below:

```
// You have to migrate Realm BEFORE open Realm if you changed schema definitions 
setSchemaVersion(1, Realm.defaultPath) { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) -> Void in
    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
        // Nothing to do!
        // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
        // And will update the schema on disk automatically
    }
}

let realm = Realm()
...
```

Comment: but where is "setSchemaVersion" from?

Comment: @User9527 This answer is for too old version. In latest version, you can use `Realm.Configuration` to specify schema version instead. See also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations